# How to vertically justify text data labels in R barplot along the y-axis?

Tags: r

The following code provides a simple illustration of the issue:

```
testX = c(9, 10, 15, 100, 8)
barX <- barplot(testX, ylim=c(0, max(testX)))
text(x=barX, y=5, labels=round(testX), xpd=TRUE, srt=90)
barX
```

I would like the vertical text data labels to be left justified (along the y-axis... "bottom justified" if you will), rather than the default center justification seen here; (in the final two columns, see how the "100" starts lower than the "8".... in a larger plot with more columns, this becomes very unsightly):
[image]

Comment: I don't think so; the x-axis labels are fine; it's the data label justification I'm concerned with; I've modified the question to clarify this - thanks!

Comment: I meant `text(x=barX-0.4, y=5, labels=round(testX), xpd=TRUE, srt=90)
`

Comment: Aha, I see.  Since it's displayed vertically, the left justification I'm after is along the y-axis, not the x-axis.  (Hence my "bottom justified" comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to add to the `text` function this options:

```
text(x=barX, y= 4, labels=round(testX), xpd = T, srt=90,  adj = c(0,0))
```